# Quadratic optimisation with $\ell_1$ constraints with CVXPY

Tags: optimization, python, convex-optimization, cvxpy, disciplined-convex-programming

<sub>[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4780307) on Mathematics SE</sub>

---

I seek to minimize a convex quadratic objective subject to linear and $\ell_1$-based equality constraints. When I turn to CVXPY, an error is raised indicating that it does **not** follow DCP rules. In what ways would it violate DCP? Naively, I thought this would be a common problem so would be handled by CVXPY out of the box.

```py
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

n = 5
A = np.random.randn(n, n)
E = np.eye(n)
w = cp.Variable(n)
problem = np.Problem(
   cp.Minimize(cp.quad_form(w, E)),
   [
      A.T @ w == 0,
      cp.norm(w, 1) == 1
   ]
prob.solve()
```

Comment: When software misbehaves, it is good practice to always copy-paste all details from the log that might be relevant to debugging the issue.

Comment: Also, np.Problem should be cp.Problem, you are missing a right parenthesis before the last line, and prob.solve() should be problem.solve()

Comment: Is $w$ supposed to be nonnegative?

Answer (score 5):

`cp.norm(w, 1) == 1` is a nonlinear equality constraint, hence violates DCP rules. It is a non-convex constraint.

Unless there is some special CVXPY mode or add-on to handle this, i believe you would need to introduce binary variables to handle this constraint, as shown in [section 9.1.7 "Exact 1-norm" of the "Mosek Modeling Cookbook"](https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#integer-modeling).

Note that `cp.norm(w, 1) <= 1` is a DCP-compliant convex constraint. But `cp.norm(w, 1) >= 1` is non-convex, and is non-DCP-compliant.

The formulation in the Mosek Modeling Cookbook gets around this by shifting the non-convexity into the binary variables. I.e., the declaration of a variable as binary or integer is in and of itself a non-convex constraint, but one which CVXPY and similar convex optimization modeling tools allow, presuming the continuous relaxation is DCP-compliant.

P.S. In the future, please follow the advice in @Henrik Alsing Friberg 's comment to show all the modeling tool and solver log output.